# Prefix the contents of a file using content of another file having a single line

Tags: sed

I am trying to insert the contents of a `file1.txt` into `file2.txt` using `sed`. The content of `file1.txt` is just a single line, which is a path.
I want it to be added as a prefix to each line in `file2.txt` as well as add another `/` character.

```
$ cat file1.txt
/psot/rot8888/orce/db/tier/data/tine

$ cat file2.txt
o1_mf_users_abchwfg_.dbf
o1_mf_toptbs2_abchrq0_.dbf
o1_mf_toptbs1_abchrl2_.dbf
o1_mf_toptbs1_abchtlf_.dbf
```

Desired output should be like:

```
/psot/rot8888/orce/db/tier/data/tine/o1_mf_users_abchwfg_.dbf
/psot/rot8888/orce/db/tier/data/tine/o1_mf_toptbs2_abchrq0_.dbf
/psot/rot8888/orce/db/tier/data/tine/o1_mf_toptbs1_abchrl2_.dbf
/psot/rot8888/orce/db/tier/data/tine/o1_mf_toptbs1_abchtlf_.dbf
```

Tried command:

```
$ sed '/o1/ r file1.txt' file2.txt >> test.txt    
$ cat test.txt
o1_mf_users_abchwfg_.dbf
/psot/rot8888/orce/db/tier/data/tine
o1_mf_toptbs2_abchrq0_.dbf
/psot/rot8888/orce/db/tier/data/tine
o1_mf_toptbs1_abchrl2_.dbf
/psot/rot8888/orce/db/tier/data/tine
o1_mf_toptbs1_abchtlf_.dbf
/psot/rot8888/orce/db/tier/data/tine
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pr` for this without having to worry about `sed` metacharacters, delimiters, etc.

```
$ cat ip.txt
abcd.xyz
123.txt
foo_baz.txt
$ cat f1
/a/b/c/d/

$ pr -mts"$(< f1)" /dev/null ip.txt
/a/b/c/d/abcd.xyz
/a/b/c/d/123.txt
/a/b/c/d/foo_baz.txt
```

Where `-m` allows pasting files parallely and `-s` is the separator between the files to be merged. Here, `/dev/null` is used as a dummy for one of the files as only the separator has to be prefixed.

---

If you need to add some more characters after the contents of file containing the prefix:

```
$ cat ip.txt
abcd.xyz
123.txt
foo_baz.txt
$ cat f1
/a/b/c/d
$ pr -mts"$(< f1)"'/' /dev/null ip.txt
/a/b/c/d/abcd.xyz
/a/b/c/d/123.txt
/a/b/c/d/foo_baz.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{p=$0; next} {print p "/" $0}' file1 file2
/psot/rot8888/orce/db/tier/data/tine/o1_mf_users_abchwfg_.dbf
/psot/rot8888/orce/db/tier/data/tine/o1_mf_toptbs2_abchrq0_.dbf
/psot/rot8888/orce/db/tier/data/tine/o1_mf_toptbs1_abchrl2_.dbf
/psot/rot8888/orce/db/tier/data/tine/o1_mf_toptbs1_abchtlf_.dbf
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1h;1d;G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/' file1 file2
```

Copy file1 into the hold space and append it to each line in file2. Using regexp and back references, manipulate the two lines into one in the correct order.

Alternative:

```
sed 'x;s/.*/cat file1/e;G;s/\n//' file2
```

Insert file1 into the hold space, append the current line of file2, and remove the newline connecting them.

A third way:

```
sed 'r file1' file2 | sed -E 'N;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2\/\1/'
```

Comment: Thanks...Same as before ,... i tried this...But i am getting. /psot/rot8888/orce/db/tier/data/tineo1_mf_users_abchwfg_.dbf /psot/rot8888/orce/db/tier/data/tineo1_mf_toptbs2_abchrq0_.dbf instead of /psot/rot8888/orce/db/tier/data/tine/o1_mf_users_abchwfg_.dbf /psot/rot8888/orce/db/tier/data/tine/o1_mf_toptbs2_abchrq0_.dbf

Comment: @user11458850 perhaps the lines of file1 do not end in `/`. In this cast replace `\n` by `\/` in the LHS of the substitute command.